# ASP.NET CORE 2.1 Server timeout while debugging

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

> 'Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the
>   server.'.

I'm trying to debug some server-side code and while I do that the client gets disconnected in less than a minute.

I'm only using SignalR to communicate to clients, without controllers yet.

Is there any setting that can disable timeout or at least make it way longer than it is now?

my launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:26793",
      "sslPort": 44386
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT": "44386"
      }
    },
    "Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which server, IIS Express + Kestrel? That's a known issue. Try switching the launch profile to just kestrel.

Comment: @Tratcher

I edited the post and added my launchSettings.json.  I think it launches 
Kestrel only given what the docs say: 

**When the application is launched with dotnet run, the first profile with "commandName": "Project" will be used. The value of commandName specifies the web server to launch. commandName can be one of : IIS Express; IIS; Project (which launches Kestrel)** 

So I guess the "Api" profile will be used with Kestrel right?

Comment: Makes sense. Reading that error again it sounds like it's coming from the SignalR client, not the server.

Comment: @Tratcher I'm using the latest version of both angular and signalR, I have no idea what the problem could be. Thanks anyway :D

Comment: Are you still noticing this issue? I have a similar issue and I'm on JavaScript client. Can't link my question here I guess but one of the answers to my question was to try set HubConnection.ServerTimeout to a higher value. If you're on a .NET client you can see if that helps?

Comment: @Kodathon client is also javascript, though still thank you.

Comment: @ArhireIonut Have you found a solution ?

Comment: @MahmoudFarahat   
`this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('http://localhost:5000/match').build();

    this._hubConnection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 1000 * 1000;` 

I tried to increase serverTimeoutInMilliseconds but haven't tested it beause I am very busy with other things right now. If you try it and it works please answer my post accordingly.

Comment: Yes this worked for me , I can now debug with no problem

Thanks a lot 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to [@Arhire Ionut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7766563/arhire-ionut)

Here is how to increase Javascript client timeout

```
hubConnection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 100000; // 100 second
```

More details here => https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/6885

Comment: It's worth noting that even with this tweak if you run your SignalR server behind IIS 8.5+ that is websocket-aware then (if we assume IIS has the default settings) IIS will kill any and all websocket connections that are inactive for 2 mins regardless of what value you specify on .serverTimeoutInMilliseconds. So in order to achieve optimum results in your dev-environment also remember to tweak your IIS in your dev machines.

Comment: Where do you set this? There's no context given.

Answer (score 12):

What @MahmoudFarhat mentioned in another answer is correct. [But also take a look at this link](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events.md#how-to-notify-the-user-about-disconnections) and then read my comments below.

If signalR got disconnected, you should try re-establishing the connection again. The connection could drop for several other reasons, including the user switching networks. For example if the user is using a cell-phone and connected to the home/office Wifi but steps out which then connects to cellular data connection.

To reconnect you could use the following (works like a charm for me):

```
// re-establish the connection if connection dropped
connection.onclose(() => setTimeout(startSignalRConnection(connection), 5000));
```

where `startSignalRConnection` is :

```
const startSignalRConnection = connection => connection.start()
  .then(() => console.info('Websocket Connection Established'))
  .catch(err => console.error('SignalR Connection Error: ', err));
```

and connection is

```
const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(connectionHub, options)
  .withHubProtocol(protocol)
  .build();
```

Comment: An improvement upon this approach would be to employ greater and greater intervals if re-connection fails time and again and then stop trying all together after say 10 tries have been reached.

Comment: where should I call this connection.onclose

Comment: @Raj, onclose() is an event. You just subscribe to it and it will handle everything for you

Comment: Update for 2020's time travellers: Nowadays we can just use [`.WithAutomaticReconnect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#automatically-reconnect)

Answer (score 0):

send a some message on some time interval
time interval is less then serverTimeoutInMilliseconds
so before time out it will send one message and connection is alive

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).