# How to increase timeout setting in ASP.NET Core SignalR v2.1?

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying out the latest SignalR on ASP.NET Core 2.1. I have the basic app working but it times out pretty soon right now. I see this error -

> Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server.'.

Where can this timeout setting be changed? I tried the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) but no info about timeout there.
I'm running on a dev environment of Windows 10 and using JavaScript client.

Edit: Inserting image after enabling client logging.

[image]

Edit 2: Link to [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#timeout-and-keepalive-settings) containing timeouts about the older SignalR version.

Comment: I would turn on client logging first to see why you aren't getting keep  alive messages,

Comment: @davidfowl I've included the screenshot after enabling logging. I let the connection be idle without using the app for few seconds

Comment: @davidfowl I've increased the KeepAliveInterval in my Startup but couldn't increase ServerTimeout - could this be due to this setting?

Comment: Yes that's exactly the reason... Why did you increase the keep alive setting?

Comment: Oh. Thank you for clarifying ! It was my fault, I wanted a bit longer timeout than the default so I tried increasing it but saw this side effect. Still trying to find a way to increase timeout though, any suggestions? Only thing I found was in signalr.js - var DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_MS = 10 * 1000; but it is not available outside for my client.

Comment: @davidfowl One more thing - I've edited the question to have a link to the previous version's docs. Does the same concept & default timeout values still hold with the latest SignalR, as I don't see them in the new docs?

Comment: Surely the answer is just don't change the timeouts...? It's got good defaults already

Comment: I would like to change the timeouts during dev at least and would also like to understand how to do so, if possible. Having a Default doesn't mean I should not even try to explore. Sure it broke but I learnt from it.

Comment: Change it on both client and server

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET CORE 2.1 Server timeout while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816245/asp-net-core-2-1-server-timeout-while-debugging)

Comment: @MahmoudFarahat I'll try this out early next week

Comment: @MahmoudFarahat this worked for me. I'll select the answer in that link. This question will now be a duplicate but the answer was updated last week so I couldn't find this initially.

Comment: Also read my comments below

Answer (score 14):

For people that may come here in future:

Here is how to increase Javascript client timeout

```
hubConnection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 100000; // 100 second
```

[But also take a look at this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#notifydisconnect) and then read my comments below:

If signalR got disconnected, you should try re-establishing the connection again. The connection could drop for several other reasons, including the user switching networks. For example if the user is using a cell-phone and connected to the home/office wifi but steps out which then connects to cellular data connection.

To reconnect you could use the following (works like a charm for me):

```
// re-establish the connection if connection dropped
connection.onclose(() => setTimeout(startSignalRConnection(connection), 5000));
```

where `startSignalRConnection` is :

```
const startSignalRConnection = connection => connection.start()
  .then(() => console.info('Websocket Connection Established'))
  .catch(err => console.error('SignalR Connection Error: ', err));
```

and connection is

```
const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(connectionHub, options)
  .withHubProtocol(protocol)
  .build();
```

Comment: Second link is broken.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that link is not valid any more. I replaced that link with another useful link. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

in startup.cs

```
services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
            {
                hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.
Put the below code in the Javascript client.

```
// Connecting to the signalR
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(huburl + hubname).build();

// Setting the connection timeout
connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 180000; // 3 mins
```

Comment: How is that different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52746305/14989571) other answer?

Comment: This is the same thing.

Comment: Then please avoid posting an answer that another user has already given unless you are adding more information to it.