# SignalR not working in Windows Serrver R2 2012

Tags: asp.net, iis

I tried  a sample app using signalR as per the below guide..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

The sample app works fine in local machine and even in DEV server .
UAT server it is not working .

**UAT server configuration**

OS: Windows server R2 2012
IIS version : 8.5
Application :Dot net
Framework : Asp . net core 2.0

**Issue :**

The signal demo app is working in visual studio .When i hosted to IIS . it is not working .The issue i am facing is the following :

signalr.js:3082 [2020-08-31T07:17:32.162Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server.'.
Chat.js:19 Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server.

**console error screenshot:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fqGe.png)

I have enabled Web socket protocol in add feature menu.
Did i missing any thing? For some reason it couldn't able to connect to the hub.

Comment: Sounds like there is a 404 error. Read IIS log files to see what's the substatus code and resolve it first, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase Javascript client timeout.

```
hubConnection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 100000; // 100 second
```

If signalR got disconnected, you should try re-establishing the connection again. The connection could drop for several other reasons, including the user switching networks. For example if the user is using a cell-phone and connected to the home/office wifi but steps out which then connects to cellular data connection.

You can also refer to below links of a similar case with the issue:
[How to increase timeout setting in ASP.NET Core SignalR v2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336870/how-to-increase-timeout-setting-in-asp-net-core-signalr-v2-1?rq=1)

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "PPSDBA"."EV_ADDEVENT" (
    p_EVENT_TYPE_ID NUMBER,
    p_EVENT_STATUS VARCHAR2(255),
    p_EVENT_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(512),
    p_NOTES VARCHAR2(255),
    p_USER_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    p_EVENT_DATE DATE,
    p_COMPONENT_INFO1 VARCHAR2(50),
    p_COMPONENT_INFO2 VARCHAR2(50),
    p_COMPONENT_INFO3 VARCHAR2(50),
    p_SOURCE VARCHAR2(20),
    p_PROCESSED_DATE DATE,
    p_TERMINAL VARCHAR2(50),
    p_ERROR_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(512),
    p_ERROR_CODE NUMBER
) AS

Comment: v_Event_Type_Id NUMBER := 0; -- Default to 0
BEGIN
    -- Check if the provided EVENT_TYPE_ID exists in VENDOR_EVENT_TYPE_DICT
    SELECT Event_Type_Id INTO v_Event_Type_Id
    FROM PPSDBA.VENDOR_EVENT_TYPE_DICT
    WHERE Event_Type_Id = p_EVENT_TYPE_ID;

    -- If no rows are returned, v_Event_Type_Id remains 0

Comment: BEGIN
        INSERT INTO PPSDBA.VENDOR_EVENT_LOG (
            EVENT_TYPE_ID,
            EVENT_STATUS,
            EVENT_MESSAGE,
            NOTES,
            USER_NAME,
            EVENT_DATE,
            COMPONENT_INFO1,
            COMPONENT_INFO2,
            COMPONENT_INFO3,
            SOURCE,
            PROCESSED_DATE,
            TERMINAL,
            ERROR_MESSAGE,
            ERROR_CODE
        ) VALUES (

Comment: v_Event_Type_Id,
            p_EVENT_STATUS,
            p_EVENT_MESSAGE,
            p_NOTES,
            p_USER_NAME,
            p_EVENT_DATE,
            p_COMPONENT_INFO1,
            p_COMPONENT_INFO2,
            p_COMPONENT_INFO3,
            p_SOURCE,
            p_PROCESSED_DATE,
            p_TERMINAL,
            p_ERROR_MESSAGE,
            p_ERROR_CODE
        );
        COMMIT;

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Event inserted successfully');
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Event Type');
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK; -- Rollback the transaction on error
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('An Error Occurred: ' || SQLERRM);
    END;
END;
/
GRANT EXECUTE ON "PPSDBA"."EV_ADDEVENT" TO AUTOMED_APP_ROLE;